# MYSQL and python error

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert data in MYSQL database using python 
here my code

```
import MySQLdb
#connect to db
db= MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
              user="root",
              passwd="newpassword",
              db="new_schema")
#setup cursor
cursor = db.cursor()
#create anooog1 table
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS try")
sql = """CREATE TABLE try (
      COL1 INT,            COL2 INT )"""
cursor.execute(sql)


#insert to table
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO try VALUES (%s,%s)""",(188,90))
db.commit()   
db.rollback()
#show table
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM try""")

print cursor.fetchall()
db.close()
```

but the error is in my sql

```
Error: `new_schema`.`try`: table data is not editable because there is no primary key defined for the table ...
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Why are you doing `rollback` after `commit`?

Comment: How about defining the primary key?

Comment: `alter table try add primary key (col1)`, perhaps?

Comment: The above script works fine and the error seems to come from another tool than MySQLdb. You can of course insert data into a table without primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because you've created a table with no primary key.

Use this statement (or similar):

```
sql = """CREATE TABLE try (COL1 INT, COL2 INT, PRIMARY KEY (COL1))"""
```

Here we specify that `COL1` is to be the primary key for the table. Modify as you need to suit your requirements.

If you wanted to add a string column (with length 128) to your table:

```
 CREATE TABLE try (COL1 INT, COL2 INT, MyString VARCHAR(128), PRIMARY KEY (COL1))
```

Comment: @roro: you're welcome! Be sure to use the green checkmark for all your questions when you've found the best answer.

Comment: cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO opa VALUES (%s,%s)""",("lolo","ghost"))

Comment: OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Comment: @roro: You have 1 or 3 or 4 or ... columns defined for the table but you are passing in 2 values

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @roro: You have more args than format slots e.g. `"foo %s bar" % (1, 2, 3)` has 3 args and 1 slot. BTW, this is the 3rd add-on question you've asked in comments. About time to ask a new question! Also time to acquire some simple self-help skills e.g. google("not all arguments converted during string formatting")