# table not editable mysql workbench error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table that has no primary key.  All I want to do is see the data.  I DO NOT WANT TO EDIT IT.  Yet, whenever I run this query...

```
SELECT * FROM TableThatHasNoPrimaryKey
```

MySQL Workbench (version 5.2.36 v8542, running on Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit) gives me this error...

```
table data is not editable because there is no primary key defined for the table
```

Is this a bug?  This query displays the data just fine on MySQL browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on internet:

try this launch the workbench using:

```
"mysql-workbench --log-level=debug3"
```

it's a bug, take a look here:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62893

if not you will have to add a primary key, take a look to this forum

[MYSQL and python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723414/mysql-and-python-error)

Comment: Thanks, although I was hoping that there was a setting I had to check/uncheck. *sigh* I guess I'll have to put up with this for now.  I really wish Linux had a Sequel Pro port.

Answer (score 6):

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM TableWithNoPrimaryKey
) AS tmp

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround

```
select *, char_length('') from tableName
```

Using a function in the select statement gets around the issue

Answer (score 0):

I use this as a workaround:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TempTableThatHasNoPrimaryKey;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTableThatHasNoPrimaryKey
SELECT *
FROM TableThatHasNoPrimaryKey;

SELECT * FROM TempTableThatHasNoPrimaryKey
```

for some strange reason this works...

Answer (score 0):

To open a table in edit mode in *mysql workbench* you need to have a **primary key** column in your table.Otherwise it always be opened in read mode only.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to fetch data from the table, you may create `Views` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting workbench fixed it for me.